# Git submodule absolute worktree path config

Tags: git, git-submodules

This is my submodule **redmine_dashboard** config file:

### Submodule config file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    worktree = /Users/daniel/redmine/vendor/plugins/redmine_dashboard
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github.com:ebc/redmine_dashboard.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[gui]
    wmstate = normal
    geometry = 841x391+-8+43 187 177
```

### Mac

```
worktree = /Users/daniel/redmine/vendor/plugins/redmine_dashboard
```

### Linux

```
worktree = /home/daniel/redmine/vendor/plugins/redmine_dashboard
```

### Issue

Can I change this absolute path for a relative? Something like:

```
worktree = ../../vendor/plugins/redmine_dashboard
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you should be able to update the config file with a relative path. You should also update the worktree dir in the `.git` file in the submodule root to be a relative path back to that module.

I believe this is fixed in (at least) the most current version of git (1.7.10.1). I can't seem to find a changelog, so I have no idea when it got fixed. I was able to have git fix the issue by deleting both the submodule and the folder in the `.git/modules` folder and then redoing `git submodule init` and `git submodule update`.

Comment: I was having a very problem after moving my git "supermodule" to a new local directory.  Based in this answer, I build git from source to obtain 1.7.11.3, and then running a `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` automatically reconfigured all of the submodule roots.

Comment: So to clarify the only fix is to edit a bunch of files or build from source. apt-get currently has 1.7.9 version for git.

Comment: Note that if you have an old repository and you have originally cloned the submodules with older variant of git you'll have absolute paths in `.git/modules/**/config`. Recent git versions *will* generate relative paths by default but OLD configuration files will not be automatically rewritten to use relative paths.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the [`git config` man page](http://man.he.net/man1/git-config) mentions:

core.worktree

> Set the path to the root of the work tree. This can be overridden by the `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable and the `--work-tree` command line option.
>   It can be an absolute path **or a relative path to the `.git` directory**, either specified by `--git-dir` or `GIT_DIR`, or automatically discovered.
>   If `--git-dir` or `GIT_DIR` are specified but none of `--work-tree`, `GIT_WORK_TREE` and `core.worktree` is specified, the current working directory is regarded as the root of the work tree.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you setting `worktree` at all? By default, the work tree is where you run your commands from, where the `.git` directory is. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5283262/53013) for more information.

Comment: @daniel-c-sobral I made something like [this](http://help.github.com/submodules/), so this path was created by `git add submodule` command. When my **Dropbox** syncronized that source code from Linux to other SO, like MAC or Win for example, the tree was broken: `fatal: Not a git repository: /home/daniel/redmine/vendor/plugins/redmine_dashboard`.

Comment: More like *Why is git making these absolute paths for us?*