# Version control: from zip to git

Tags: git, version-control

I have three zipped folders named [1,2,3] each contains the same project 1 being the earliest and 3 being the most current. I am looking for a way to merge all of these into 3 git commits and the 3 most commit be the folders contents.

I suppose I can do the following:

1. Unzip 1.
2. Take the contents from 1 place it into a new folder.
3. `git init`
4. `git add -A`
5. `git commit -m "first commit`
6. Unzip 2
7. replace the contents from the new folder with contents from 2
8. `git add -A`
9. `git commit -m "second commit`
10. Unzip 2
11. replace the contents from the new folder with contents from 3
12. `git add -A`
13. `git commit -m "third commit`

Could anyone tell me if this is the best way to do this?

Comment: The git init step would seem un-necessary except in the first step.

Comment: The extra git init's where a copy and paste error thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you run `git init`, you're creating an empty repository.

If there are only three folders and you're only doing it once, then this will work (if you omit `git init`). Just make sure not to erase the `.git` folder.

You could even unzip the three folders and move the `.git` folder to each in succession and commit in each separate folder, with the final folder being the start of your new repository.

Answer (score 5):

Unzip your three zip file in three different directories.

Initialize a git repo in a *fourth* directory.

Then take advantage of the [`--work-tree` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8926472/6309), which allows you to execute a git command from a git repo, but with a content located *outside* of said git repo:

```
cd /your/git/repo
git add --work-tree=/path/to/zip1 -A .
git commit -m "Add v1"
git add --work-tree=/path/to/zip2 -A .
git commit -m "Add v1"
git add --work-tree=/path/to/zip3 -A .
git commit -m "Add v3"
```

In other words, you can add different contents without moving from your git directory!

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would approach this

Get Version 1 commited

```
mkdir MyProj
cd MyProj
git init
# unzip version1 into MyProj
git add -A
git commit -m "Version 1"
```

Get Version 2 committed

```
# delete everything but the .git directory in MyProject
# unzip version2 into MyProj
git add -A 
git commit -m "Version 2"
```

Get Version 3 committed

Repeat the above for version3 of the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just make sure to fully replace the contents, and catch all added and removed files.