# How can I cache untracked (binary) files associated to a branch?

Tags: git, version-control, compilation

Assume I am one of many developers working with git on a huge code project, which has an **incredibly long compilation time**.

Now, my personal day-to-day changes are usually limited, and the codebase is decently modular, which means that as far as my *personal* work is concerned, **compiling from scratch is a price that only has to be paid once**. Afterwards, I can recompile only the modules I modified.

On the other hand, **I frequently have to fix bugs in** (at least two) **branches which reflect states of the codebase completely distinct from the branch I work on**. Those two branches are indeed the result of work from the entire development team, and often have entire modules rewritten or added. **Having compiled everything before pushing a bugfix is mandatory**.

My first approach was to switch from my development branch every time a bugfix is needed, then clean, bugfix, recompile from scratch, push, switch back to the original branch, clean again, recompile - **the delay for doing this is intolerable**.

I then moved to **keeping three separate checkouts of the codebase on my machine**. This solves the "*costly recompilation*" problem (my changes in every branch are incremental again), but it makes the question "what am I developing on right now ?" more complex to answer (since it depends on the current directory), and it makes synchronization of these three copies complex (it multiplies all the routine `push`/`remote update`/`pull` commands I have to do by three).

A simpler solution would be **to have the ability to save the state of a directory** (untracked, where I generate compiled files) **every time my checkout "leaves"a branch, and to recall the state of that directory, if it exists, every time I "enter"** (checkout) **a branch**.

- Are there git commands that would help me achieve this behavior ?
- If not, is there a tool that would allow me to do that ?
- If not, does git provide checkout hooks that could help me script this behavior ?

Comment: A not so elegant solution is to append, for example, the branch name,  to the compilation output folder, and rename it back when you are working on that branch.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I think that's the most elegant solution as long as all those folders are inside a common folder so you don't clutter the root source folder with those folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use stashes, they are pretty close to what you need.

In recent versions of git, you can stash untracked files with the `--include-untracked` option. You can also give messages to your stashes and recall them, so you can check in which stash must be applied after checking out a branch.

```
#before leaving branch
git stash save --include-untracked "compiled stuff for my_branch"
git checkout another_branch
#what stash contains compiled stuff for another_branch?
git stash list
git stash pop stash@{n}
```

You can script a bit to make things more practical...

Comment: Thanks a lot ! very good suggestion ! I think you have to put the `--include-untracked` *after* the `save` command though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I do not have exact answers as I did not have to deal with a case like yours, but anyway I'd like to provide possible hint: Git is able to use several distinct work trees "connected" to a single repository (read more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5283457/720999) for instance), so instead of maintaining multiple checkouts, you can just use multiple work trees with a single repository.

I should add that I like @CharlesB's solution better (conceptually) but on the other hand I would measure: supposedly `git stash` would effectively *copy* your files when turning them into blobs to store in the stash which would a) temporarily double the space occupied by those huge files on the filesystem; b) have unknown long-standing effect on the size of the Git's object database size.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents : keep track of the compilation directory as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules%20submodule) - but as I haven't used this git feature yet, I can only point you to the doc page...