# Git: local repository and working tree the same?

Tags: git

I am relatively new to Git. I created a new local repository, in my Windows machine, by issuing `git init` command (say, inside `d:\testproj` folder). i then configured Eclipse (my java ide) to point to this directory and started working on it. i then executed "git add" and "git commit" commands from the testproj folder. All commands executed successfully.

My question is: Is `testproj` the working tree or git local repository?

PS: Meanwhile, i was looking for answers in stackoverflow and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5283457/291475. I then came to a conclusion that `.git` directory is the local repository and `testproj` is the working directory. Is that correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.  The `.git` directory contains everything that makes it a git repo.  And it's where the history (commits) of your working tree (in this case, testproj) is kept.  Deleting it would essentially remove the git out of that directory.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't clear with your answer. Did you say that .git is local repo and testproj is working tree?

Comment: Another related question. If i need to setup a project that spans multiple repositories, how do i do it?

Comment: You could setup a git repository with git submodules:

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: git submodules are considered sub optimal, consider instead https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree
Read here for a more in-depth of why: http://uttamkini.com/2012/12/01/sharing-code-and-why-git-submodules-is-a-bad-idea/