# Git commit dumps random files

Tags: git, github, version-control

I've been having issues with adding files to my commits. In short, whenever I do git add , the files added to the unstaged commit are from the Git folder in my Program files dir (to clarify, I'm using an x64 version of windows 8). Regardless of what I do (git init, git clone...etc.), I have the same issue across all of my repositories. Is there something I'm missing? Also, this happens regardless of tool choice( git bash, powershell, cygwin, tortoise-git). If it helps, I'll also provide any snippets / images upon request. Update: Git deletes the repo files tracked and replaces them with files from `../Program Files/Git`.

Comment: So... what is your current directory when you do a `git add`?

Comment: The current dir would be any of my working repos. For example, I'd be on C:\Users\Me\Repository(master), and none of the files in said repo would be tracked. The only files tracked are in my ..\Program Files\Git dir

Comment: Take this as a constructive critique: it's kind of hard to understand your situation. I think the best you can do is appending a transcript of a terminal session showing how you create the repo (if applies), add and commit the files, and what `ls`/`dir`, `git status` and `git diff` show, for example, so we have more context.

Comment: I have same issue - I recently install a bitcoin app (guiminer) that installed a torjan on my PC and I get this issue ever since. I removed the app, and scan for viruses - but still.

Answer (score 0):

> The only files tracked are in my ..\Program Files\Git

That could only happen if you have environment variable like `GIT_WORK_TREE` which would "trick" git into considering the folder referenced by those environment variable as its working tree (instead of the current folder you are in).

See more at "[What is `GIT_WORK_TREE`, why have I never needed to set this ENV var, why now?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5283457/6309)"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the problem may be the way you "created" your repositories.  Did you either:

1. `git clone` *url-of-some-repo* *name-of-local-dir* create/change some files then `git add`**or**
2. `git init` *name-of-local-dir* followed by `cd` *name-of-local-dir* create some files, `git add` *those files*
3. ***something else*** like just `mkdir some_name` and start trying to use git in it?

If you did **not** do one of 1 or 2 above you just have a load of files and git will not know where to put them because you don't have a repository and I guess you might see it default to where it is installed.

Comment: As said in the OP, I've used both `git init` and `git clone`, with the same result