# "git svn rebase" without changing the current branch

Tags: git, svn, rebase

I wrote a (bash) script located on my master branch and in the middle of it, I execute the following instructions:

```
(...)
git checkout featurebranch
git svn rebase
git checkout master
(...)
```

This script does not exist in the "featurebranch" so my script is aborted at the next instruction :) (you know, the man who saw the branc on which he sits :))

I don't really know how to resolve this problem since "git svn rebase" does not accept a target branch for the rebase operation, and I'm forced to checkout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a driver script that copies the main script to /tmp and executes it from there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a separate working directory to do those 3 operations.  Take a look at the answers related to GIT_WORK_TREE and "--work-tree" provided in similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283262/what-is-git-work-tree-why-have-i-never-needed-to-set-this-env-var-why-now)

Or just copy the script to your home directory and run it from there.