# GIT error: fatal: /usr/libexec/git-core/git-submodule cannot be used without a working tree

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-post-receive

I have a git repo with a submodule.

I would use in post-receive hook file:

```
git --git-dir="$GIT_DIR" --work-tree="$GIT_WORKDIR1" submodule update --init --recursive
```

but I get the following error:

```
remote: fatal: /usr/libexec/git-core/git-submodule cannot be used without a working tree.
```

I did not get solution for this problem.

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 4):

You may see this error if you've renamed the path (working-tree) of a git submodule. In my case I had updated the path in `.gitmodules` to match my new path and thought I was good. But when I did a `git pull` later it added new files in the old path. This is because there are two places the module path is defined. You need to also update your "working-tree" as defined in the `.git/modules/{modulename}/config` file.

There are some great details about the working-tree on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5283457/385979) as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I work on another task currently, will check this problem, when I return to this task.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error when running `git submodule` inside of a shell I spawned while I was running `git log` (with the `!bash` command). What also confused me was that I could run all git commands if I ran them with sudo, and that this problem affected multiple repos, not only the one I was running `git log` into.

The solution of course is to exit the subshell and the `git log` command.

Answer (score 1):

I also stumbled across this issue and found it is caused, because I needed to cd into the workdir first. I am not sure why this is required, maybe it is a git bug? You can also pass the path via `-C` and set the workdir to `.`:

```
git --git-dir="$GIT_DIR" --work-tree=. -C "$GIT_WORKDIR1" submodule update --init --recursive
```

Also I noticed that in my plesk git user interface (netcup.com) variables do not seems to work, I have to specify absolute paths without variables here:

```
git --git-dir=/git/repo_name.git --work-tree=. -C /httpdocs/website submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. It certainly appears to be a git submodule bug, where it doesn't respect `--work-tree`. It's still present as of `git version 2.39.2`

Comment: This also fixes `checkout --recurse-submodules`: `git --git-dir="${GIT_DIR}" --work-tree=. -C "${SOURCE_DIR}" checkout --recurse-submodules "${BRANCH}" -- .`

With the work-tree set directly, this would checkout the source into the work-tree directory, but silently fail to checkout any submodules.

Answer (score 0):

FYI for future readers: this also happens on Windows if you `cd` to your repo folder via a symbolic link, as the working directory reported by the OS doesn't match the truth.

Comment: It happened for me on Windows when using the Git Bash, probably for the same reason? (The 'simulated' /d/folder/repo does not match D:\folder\repo)