# git post-receive hook doesn't work as expected from remote but works when launched locally

Tags: git, git-submodules, hugo, post-update

I'm setting up git on a server to be able to compile a hugo website and publish it to /var/www/html ready to be served on the internet.

What I do in short is:

- create a temporary hugo site
- checkout the repository and its submodule (hugo theme) inside the same directory
- build with hugo deploying the static files directly to /var/www/html

What I don't understand is why `git --work-tree=$TARGET_DIR --git-dir=./ checkout -f --recurse-submodules` doesn't pull the submodule as expected.

Can anyone shed some light as to what I'm doing wrong?
Here's the script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Directory where to work on our site
TARGET_DIR=/tmp/site-compile
# Public dir where to push the site once compiled
PUBLIC_WWW="/var/www/html"
BACKUP_WWW=$HOME/site-backup
SITE_DOMAIN=https://site.ext
# repository logical name
REPO="site.ext"
# Branch that is going to be deployed to server
BRANCH="master"
# date to be appended to latest tag
NOW=$(date +"%d%m%Y-%H%M")

set -xe

# delete the working directory first
rm -rf $TARGET_DIR
# create new temporary site
/usr/local/bin/hugo new site $TARGET_DIR
# backup public www directory first then setup trap
rsync -avz --no-t $PUBLIC_WWW/ $BACKUP_WWW
trap "echo 'A problem occurred.  Reverting to backup.'; rsync -avz --no-t --del $BACKUP_WWW/ $PUBLIC_WWW; rm -rf $TARGET_DIR" EXIT

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
        # if TARGET_DIR is empty we don't want deploy for this project
        if [[ ! $TARGET_DIR == "" ]]; then
                if [[ "$GL_REPO" == "$REPO" ]]; then
                        # let's check that we are deploying to the correct branch
                        if [[ $ref = refs/heads/${BRANCH} ]]; then
                                echo "Ref $ref received. Deploying '${BRANCH}' branch to production..."
                                git --work-tree=$TARGET_DIR --git-dir=./ checkout -f --recurse-submodules
                                rm ${TARGET_DIR}/config.toml
                                rm -rf $PUBLIC_WWW/*
                                /usr/local/bin/hugo -s $TARGET_DIR -d $PUBLIC_WWW -b "${SITE_DOMAIN}" -t "dagreynix" --noTimes --minify
                                git tag release_$NOW $BRANCH
                                echo "   /==============================="
                                echo "   | DEPLOYMENT COMPLETED - ${REPO}"
                                echo "   | Target branch: ${BRANCH}"
                                echo "   | Target folder: ${PUBLIC_WWW}"
                                echo "   | Tag name     : release_${NOW}"
                                echo "   \=============================="
                        else
                                echo "Ref $ref received. Doing nothing: only the ${BRANCH} branch may be deployed on this server."
                        fi
                fi
        else
                echo "Target directory not declared. Skipping deploy to server."
        fi
done

rm -rf $TARGET_DIR
trap - EXIT
```

The site.ext repository contains the `content/` directory, `hugo.toml` settings file and `static/` directory, the submodule is a hugo theme.

In short the post-receive script should update the submodule in themes/theme-folder and pull the relative files, otherwise hugo can't properly build the site.

Thanks in advance

**[EDIT]**

I've solved thanks to @VonC by following this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75486042/git-post-receive-hook-doesnt-work-as-expected-from-remote-but-works-when-launch/75490414?noredirect=1#comment133199871_75490414)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the submodule was not initialized first, try a

```
git submodule init
```

Then your [`git checkout -f --recurse-submodules`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---recurse-submodules) should have a chance to update the submodule content according to the commit recorded in the superproject.

The OP confirms however that, as illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64621032/6309), you need to be in the working tree for `git submodule init` to work.

So instead of:

```
git --work-tree=$TARGET_DIR --git-dir=./
```

Do:

```bash
GIT_DIR=$(pwd)
cd "${TARGET_DIR}"
git --work-tree=./ --git-dir="${GIT_DIR}"/ submodule init
```

Comment: thanks @VonC, but it doesn't work, I've modified the line like this

```git --work-tree=$TARGET_DIR --git-dir=./ checkout -f
git --work-tree=$TARGET_DIR --git-dir=./ submodule init
git --work-tree=$TARGET_DIR --git-dir=./ submodule update --init```
but submodule init complains that it can't be used without a working tree

I don't get it.

Comment: Just to integrate, I've tried explicitly declaring the GIT_DIR directory and `checkout -f` works, but `submodule init` still complains that git-submodule can't be used without a working tree.
I don't understand why one git subcommand works and the other doesn't.

Comment: @danix is `$TARGET_DIR` empty?

Comment: no, it is populated by hugo before the `git checkout -f`, but the checkout command is not complaining and the files are checked out correctly, `git submodule init` is complaining even though the destination folder of the submodule is empty and the work tree is populated before I run the command

Comment: this is the output from the remote
```
remote: Ref refs/heads/master received. Deploying 'master' branch to production...
remote: + git --work-tree=/tmp/danix.xyz-compile checkout -f
remote: + git --work-tree=/tmp/danix.xyz-compile submodule init
remote: fatal: /usr/lib/git-core/git-submodule cannot be used without a working tree.
```

Comment: @danix Maybe cd to the worktree, and reference your gitdir path instead of the current command which does the opposite. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64621032/6309) as an example.

Comment: @danix I have seen your edit, and I have edited my answer to reflect the proper setup for `git submodule init` to work.