# Git Stash & Worktree Woes

Tags: git, git-stash

I'm having difficulty getting Git to cooperate with my user-defined worktree that exists **outside** the folder that contains my .git directory.

Basically the setup is like this: I have two directories, one called "git-worktree" which houses the file I want to track & another called "git-dir" which contains the repository's .git folder aka the GIT_DIR.

I init the repository by cd'ing into folder "git-dir" and running:

```
git --git-dir=./.git --work-tree=/Users/braitsch/Test/git-worktree/ init
```

This successfully initializes the repository and while I'm in the "git-dir" folder I can add files that are in the work-tree, run git status and commit them. Cool.

The kick comes when I try to run `git stash`, which slaps me with the error:

```
fatal: /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-stash cannot be used without a working tree.
```

Now this is nonsense, because I know (or at least I think) I have the work-tree set to the "git-worktree" folder that contains the files I want to track.

`git config --local -l` shows me the following :

```
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.worktree=/Users/braitsch/Test/git-worktree
core.ignorecase=true
```

I even tried manually adding the .git folder to the local config file to see if that helps but to no avail.

```
core.gitdir=/Users/braitsch/Test/git-dir/.git
```

Now here comes the kicker. Git stash will work **if I set the worktree to a directory that is a parent of the git-dir** e.g. If I set the worktree to say my home directory.

```
core.worktree=/Users/braitsch/
```

So the question I have is what setting am I missing to tell Git to allow my worktree to exist ***anywhere*** on the filesystem, not just along a parent path of the git-dir back up to the root? Surely there must be a way to place your git-dir & your work-tree wherever you want and after telling Git where they are, and have everything work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
git --git-dir=<your path> --work-tree=<work tree path> stash
```

should work. Have you tried absolute paths?

UPDATE:

seems to be a bug. The extended functionality of --git-dir option was only added recently and some commands like git stash don't have the new implementation yet.

git-stash is a bash script. You could hack it and remove the require working dir check then cd into the working folder.

Comment: `git --git-dir=/Users/braitsch/Test/git-dir/.git/ --work-tree=/Users/braitsch/Test/git-worktree/ stash` still gives me the error saying that I don't have a worktree.

Comment: interesting.. could be a bug.. let me confirm.

Comment: Yup.. seems to be a bug in git stash.

Comment: After looking at some of the commit messages in the repo for the git project, it looks like git dir was originally supposed to be only used when in a subdirectory within the working dir that has a .git folder at the top level. It's only recently that it's been supported to work with arbitrary dirs. Maybe I'll send in a patch for stash.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for taking the time to look into this. If you submit a patch I'd love to know. In the meantime, I found that cd'ing into the actual worktree and then calling stash by preceding the path to the git-dir works but it's kind of a pain switching back and forth between the worktree & the git-dir just to execute one command over another. For the record here's my ghetto workaround until this bug is fixed : `cd /Users/braitsch/Test/git-worktree` `git --git-dir=/Users/braitsch/Test/git-dir/.git/ stash list` Cheers -S

Comment: you can flip between 2 different dirs by calling `cd -` repeatedly. Hope this helps.

Comment: Has this been fixed? I didn't see any commits to the [public repository][1] related to it and I don't know how to access any kind of official issue tracker.


  [1]: https://github.com/git/git/commits/master