# NetBeans Java - How to add external library (jar) to git repository

Tags: java, netbeans, github

I am looking for a best practices workflow for doing this.

Currently what I know how to do is get my new repository and project created in netbeans, then I manually create a folder in my new project folder called libraries, copy my jar file to this folder, then add the library.  If I add the library to my global libraries or import it from its own folder, git does not include the file in my commits.  So do I need to just be doing this slightly manual process or is there some other workflow I should follow?

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383754/git-how-do-you-add-an-external-directory-to-the-repository) which has some workflows that either involve symbolic links or `git --work-tree=/ add /home/some/directory`.  Is there any built in netbeans solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer to this is pretty simple.  Just right click the Libraries folder under your project and add the library (likely through adding a jar file).

Then under your project properties, make sure Build=>Packaging has the `Copy Dependent Libraries` checkbox ticked.