# Git - Track a folder from a separate repository and have a separate repository set up inside of it

Tags: wordpress, git, magento, laravel, nginx

I have the following folder structure running on an NGINX server.

```
-- Laravel installation
-- Magento installation [DOCUMENT ROOT]
    -- Laravel's public folder renamed to a different name
        -- WordPress installation
```

The website structure goes something like:

```
www.example.com = Magento
www.example.com/subsite = Laravel [This is its 'public' folder.
    Rest of the folders are placed in a separate folder]
www.example.com/subsite/blogsite = WordPress [Running inside of Laravel]
```

I had to do the Laravel folder separation because I wanted to make it work as a subdirectory but somehow couldn't figure out how to do it. So I instead followed the Method #1 in [this post](http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host).

The challenge now is to manage these 3 repositories separately.

I have two major concerns:

1. How do I track the stranded Laravel public folder which is now inside the Magento repository?
2. How can I manage the WordPress installation as another separate repository?

Answer (score 0):

**1. How do I track the stranded Laravel public folder which is now inside the Magento repository?**

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8626989/1332068), you can add external directories to your working tree with this git command:

```
git --work-tree=/ add /home/some/directory
```

**2. How can I manage the WordPress installation as another separate repository?**

You can use `.gitignore` to ignore the subfolder in the Magento subfolder.

1. In the Magento root, create a file named `.gitignore`
2. In this file, create a list of folders/files you want to ignore, in your case you want to ignore the Wordpress folder within the Laravel directory (assuming it's under `public/wordpress`.

   ```
   /public/wordpress/
   /public/wordpress/*
   ```
3. Do a git commit: `git commit -am 'Ignore the Wordpress folder'`

Now you can just create a seperate git tracking instance on the Wordpress folder.

Comment: I got the `wordpress` repository working inside of the `<magento doc_root>/public/` folder. But cannot get the `public` directory to track inside `laravel` repository. It still gets tracked in the `magento` repository and when I do the `git--work-tree ...` command in `laravel` repository like you suggested, it shows files inside the `public` folder as `deleted`. And these files are also getting tracked inside `magento` repository.