# git add files from different directories

Tags: git, backup, configuration-management

I am trying to use git as a configuration management/backup solution for multiple directories. My thinking was to setup a cron job to do nightly commits and push to our central repository. What is the best way to achieve this for folders that aren't contiguous? The only thing I was thinking of was initializing the git repository in `/` and then add the folders as necessary. Is there a better way? Here are the example folders I would like to backup.

`/etc/folder1/
/opt/folder2/
/var/log/folder1/`

Comment: maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383754/git-how-do-you-add-an-external-directory-to-the-repository

Comment: What's wrong with one git repo per root folder?

Comment: too many repositories for our group. it will get messy in git that way. I read through the post that @TimothyTruckle posted  and while it definitely solves the problem, I think honestly one repo in `/` is the best bet for what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think honestly one repo in / is the best bet for what I'm looking to do.

In that case (and provided your `.gitignore` is "on point", to avoid adding *everything*), you can, for each folder, do a:

```
git -C /path/to/folder1 add .
git commit -m "Add /path/to/folder1"
git push
```

And repeat for `folder2`, `folder3`, and so on... (assuming those folders are not nested).

Comment: exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks!