# Integrate GIT repository add on module project into an existing parent Application (WHMCS) folder structure

Tags: git, devops

I am having trouble pulling and pushing a GIT project in a more automated and simpler way.

What I'm currently doing is. I have a separate folder location for the GIT project then manually copy the files back and fort, to and from the existing directory structure of the parent application. Then I do the usual git commands for committing, pulling, pushing in the separate folder.

The module have some files and folders that should be located in different folder locations of the parent application.

The module by the way is not in a single directory of the parent application.

I have found some but not so similar questions and some answers like creating symlinks is not possible.

I know that there is something out there but I can't just hit the right search query so I decided to put up a question.

The parent application is WHMCS and I am building an add-on/module?
This is the directory structure of the module/add-on project:

[image: Add On Folder Structure]

And This if the directory structure of the parent Application (WHMCS):

[image: Parent Application (WHMCS) directory structure]
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why no symlink? What OS are you using?

Comment: Hi @VonC
I am using Win 10 for local development. I am looking at the answers from this question:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383754/git-how-do-you-add-an-external-directory-to-the-repository)
Thanks

Comment: mklink is supported on W10

Comment: Thanks @VonC I will look into it