# Git: How to add an external folder (of files) into an existing repository?

Tags: git

I want to add an external directory to an existing repository. When I try in /Desktop/.git the following command: git add /home/some/directory

The following error message shows up: Fatal: '/home/some/directory' is outside repository

Is there any solution to this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383754/git-how-do-you-add-an-external-directory-to-the-repository) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git: How do you add an external directory to the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383754/git-how-do-you-add-an-external-directory-to-the-repository)

Comment: It does but somehow I'm not able to commit the add.. why?

Comment: [Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) might be what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of thing is outside the *design* of Git.  I don't really want to close this as a duplicate of [git: How do you add an external directory to the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2383754/1256452) for several reasons:

- the person who asked that never accepted any of the answers;
- the person who owns that question isn't on StackOverflow any more; and
- none of the existing answers there really addresses all the issues.

When I mention the "design of Git" here, what I really mean is this: a Git repository is a collection of *commits*, where each commit is a *full snapshot of some set of files*.  That set-of-files all must live (and coexist) within what Git calls a *working tree* or *work-tree*.

Besides the working tree, there is also a "git dir".  This is where Git's own files—which store the repository contents—are located.  By default, the Git directory is in `.git` in the top level of the working tree.

Hence, if the *location* of the working tree, in your particular repository, is `/Desktop`, the Git directory is `/Desktop/.git`, and vice versa.  Since your Git directory is the latter, your working tree is the former.  That means every *file* stored in each commit is always relative to `/Desktop`: a file named `/dir/sub/file.ext`—or `dir/sub/file.ext`; these are interchangeable in Git, and note that there are no folders or directories involved, just forward slashes—is stored in your *working tree* as the *file* named `file.ext` in the folder named `sub` in the folder named `dir` in `/Desktop`.

In other words, Git takes the file's path—complete with embedded forward slashes—and breaks it up into components, such as `dir`, `sub`, and `file.ext`.  It then will *make the folder* `dir/sub` if needed, *making the folder* `dir` if needed.  All of this happens in your chosen worktree path.  Finally, once necessary folders exist, Git will create `file.ext` in the right folder, in your chosen worktree path.

This is all based on what's in the commits.  The commits themselves are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, format.  Each file *within* a commit is stored in a Git-only format—not your computer's format, which uses files within folders—in which each file is further compressed and, to save space, *de-duplicated* across *every* commit.  That means that if some large file is in 10,000 commits, but is the *same* in all ten thousand commits, there's really only *one copy* of that file in the repository, in Git's own internal compressed and de-duplicated format.  The file's data is stored under a *blob hash ID* name, which your computer doesn't understand.  The file's *name* is stored as more data, also compressed and de-duplicated!

The file itself is later de-compressed and turned into an ordinary file, and given a name that your computer OS understands, and put into your working tree; only then can you actually *work with* your file.  That's *one file from one commit*, and it will reside in your working tree, coexisting with every *other* file from that *same* commit, also residing in your working tree.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Git has the ability to perform what Git calls a *sparse checkout*, where not every file is copied into your working tree, but this gets rather complicated.

---

#### The `core.worktree` trick in the other question

Git has the ability to separate the Git directory and the working tree.  There are multiple ways to do this:

- `git --git-dir=path-to-.git --work-tree=path-to-working-tree command args ...`
- `GIT_DIR=path-to.git GIT_WORK_TREE=path-to-working-tree command args ...`
- `git config core.worktree path-to-working-tree`

and so on.

If and when you use these various options, you have to be careful of, and aware of, various caveats.  For instance:

- The `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` arguments set the environment variables.  (This avoids the stumbling block in the next bullet item.)
- The environment variable setting depends on your shell: not every shell uses this particular syntax.  Note that any env-var setting here may be overridden by a sub-process; the `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` arguments do this, for instance.
- If you do separate the Git directory and work-tree, make sure the Git directory is not *inside* the chosen working tree.  If it is, it may be seen as a submodule.
- Commands, including hooks, that run within these may accidentally import or fail to import these environment variables at times they should not (e.g., working inside a different work-tree) or should (e.g., during execution of a hook).  This may cause those commands to misfire.  You'll need to be able to diagnose these situations and make corrections as necessary.

Overall, this *can* be made to work: you just need to be prepared for surprises.  Because of the potential for surprises, I'd recommend always *avoiding* setting either the Git directory or the working tree to any location you cannot easily restore from some alternate copy or backup copy.