# How to add a website to GitHub from Visual Studio 2022

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I've got a website running on a virtual machine which I add to my Visual Studio solution (File -> Open -> Website) via a UNC path i.e. \server\share\websitefolder. We are trying to migrate from TFS to GitHub. Using TFS, I right click the solution and add it to source control. No problem, all files are added to TFS and I can check in/out fine. When I try the same thing using Git, it says:-

Source Control - Git

Your solution contains files outside the solution folder which will not be included. See the output window for details about which files must be manually added later.

Do you want to continue?

The trouble is, it doesn't tell you how to manually add the files later.

I've tried symlinks (soft and hard and directory) but they either can't be created or the links get uploaded to GitHub and not the actual files. I've tried git --work-tree= /add ([git: How do you add an external directory to the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383754/git-how-do-you-add-an-external-directory-to-the-repository)) but I get a fatal error saying the folder "is outside repository".

This seems like it should be so simple, and it is using TFS, but I can't seem to get it to work using Git. Any further ideas would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

I stopped trying to move the mountain and went to it instead. I had to set the default git repo location to the remote server, then it created the solution on the remote server and so the website was within the repository. It worked fine then.